# Is ORM module, sequelize dead?

Tags: database, node.js, express, orm

After installing sequelize I got this warning:

> npm WARN deprecated lingo@0.0.5: This project is abandoned

Should I use it anyway? (I saw the website is live and kicking).

Comment: It simply means that one of it's dependencies is deprecated. I wouldn't be overly concerned, and am sure this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lingo` is no longer being maintained. However, `sequelize` has already replaced `lingo` with `inflection` since [July 9th](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/87a2540c3ad1eca9758c1476c9906f6c1028c95a). This change is included in `sequelize` v2.0.0-dev13 and newer.